# Thinktecture Identity Server 4 and SSO

Tags: identityserver4

I'm doing a proof of concept, introducing OpenId Connect to our suite of products. After much discussion, we decided it would probably be better to have a separate, discreet Javascript application (Vuejs) for each product, rather than include them all in one monolithic SPA.

For this to work, we effectively need Single Sign-On **("SSO")**. I have been using IdentityServer 4 as our IDP.

I seem to have had some reasonable success by providing multiple uris to the `RedirectUris` property of the relevant Client config of the Idp. So, both apps are effectively the ***same Client***.

That does not feel right and I want to verify whether I am doing that correctly.

Here is my config for the Client config that covers the 2 SPAs (that would cover all the SPAs).

```
new Client
{
    ClientName = "Some App",
    ClientId = "appsuiteid",

    AccessTokenLifetime = 330,// 330 seconds, default 60 minutes
    IdentityTokenLifetime = 300,
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
    RequireClientSecret = false,
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true, 
    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:8080/authcallback.html",    <-- first 2 Uris for first SPA
        "http://localhost:8080/silent-refresh.html",
        "http://localhost:8090/authcallback.html",    <-- second 2 Uris for second SPA
        "http://localhost:8090/silent-refresh.html",
    },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:8080/signout-callback-oidc",
        "http://localhost:8090/signout-callback-oidc",
    },
    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
    {
        $"http://localhost:8080",
        $"http://localhost:8090",
    },
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {       
        IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile, 
    },
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("somepwd".Sha256())}
}
```

Note, if I configure a separate client for each SPA, it does not work as each SPA gets redirected to the distinct consent page for that client - thus losing the SSO characteristic which we require.

Any guidance on this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You are effectively (single) signed on, even when you have to consent. Why not just leave the consent out?

Comment: @sprengo Thanks. Yeah, it dawned on me that I don't actually need a consent screen. So, I can have separate client configs for my clients and once I am signed on, it works for all of my clients. I'll answer my own question for others.